# Where is the array stored when I used initialisation as int array[10] = {0};

Tags: c, arrays

By default, the local arrays are stored in **stack**. Uninitialised local arrays would be allocated garbage values.
But why does this syntax `int array[10] = {0};` initialises all array elements to zero by default? Even if I give `int array[10] = {10, 20}; //It initialises all rest of the elements to zero.`

Isn't it being stored on stack in this case? How does it initialise them all to zero?

Comment: The same way it initializes anything.

Comment: What's the problem here? Can't you modify there memory allocated on the stack? (yes, you can)

Comment: "By default, the local arrays are stored in stack" - Not all variables with local (i.e. block) scope are stored on the stack. And not all implementations actually use a stack at all. The standard does not require a stack.

Comment: I can see no reason why a reasonable person would down vote here.   It is an honest question about a common mis-understanding in C.

Comment: @Olaf: The OP did say "by default". In the absence of a `static` keyword, local array are stored on the "stack". Your point that not all implementations use a stack is valid. Objects with automatic storage duration must be created and destroyed in a stack-like last-in first-out manner, but they needn't be stored in "stack" allocated in contiguous memory (though that's by far the most common implementation).

Comment: @KeithThompson: "local variable" means block scope. It does not imply trhe storage duration. And no, there are indeed implementations which don't use some LIFO mechanism, but use global storage (they resolve the call-chain at compile/link-time). This of course only works for a deterministic and non-recursive code structure. Without a specific architecture the question cannot be answered.

Comment: @Olaf: Block scope with no `static` keyword does imply automatic storage duration. Implementations that don't support recursion are not conforming.

Comment: @KeithThompson: I did not say they disallow recursion. They just can store automatic variables where they want, even use more than a single allocation scheme. If they cannot resolve the call-chain, they still can fall back to a stack. But as the majority of code in that are is non-recursive, they effectively don't use a stack for typical code. There is more to optimisation than shuffle instructions and register allocation. My point is simply it is nonsense to assume all implementations behave the same. OP should know this is specific to the implementation, not a C requirement.

Comment: @Olaf: Do you expect "The standard does not require a stack" to make that point to the OP in a useful manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether or not a local array is initialized has no bearing on whether or not it is stored on stack.

If the implementation uses a stack, then the array will be on the stack, initialized or not.

From section 6.7.9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **10** If  an  object  that  has  automatic  storage  duration  is  not  initialized  explicitly,  its  value  is indeterminate.   If  an
> object  that  has  static  or  thread  storage  duration  is  not
> initialized explicitly, then:
>
> —  if it has pointer type, it is
> initialized to a null pointer;
>
> —  if it has arithmetic type, it is
> initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero;
>
> —  if it is an aggregate,
> every member is initialized (recursively) according to these rules,
> and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> —  if it is a union, the
> first named member is initialized (recursively) according to these
> rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> ...
>
> **21** If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
> are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
> string literal used to initialize an array of known size  than  there
> are  elements  in  the  array,  **the  remainder  of  the  aggregate
> shall  be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static
> storage duration**.

So if an initializer list has fewer elements than the array, the remaining elements are initialized the same as non local variables, i.e. set to 0.

Comment: So, the array is still being stored in stack but compiler is taking an extra step to initialize it to zero(as specified in standards).

Comment: @Raj Correct.  Initialization does not affect how the memory is laid out, just whether or not the contents are known.

Comment: The standard requires the remainder of the object to be initialized to zero; it says nothing about how that's implemented. The compiler will generate whatever code is necessary to meet the requirements given in the standard.  There's almost certainly no reason for you to care how it's done, but you can always examine the generated code. (@dbush: I presume you know this; this comment is mainly addressed to the OP.)